# recursively reversing a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to reverse a linked list using recursion and I the below code

```
struct node* reverse_list(struct node *head)
    {
        struct node *temp=head,*rhead,*first;
        if (temp->next== NULL)
            return temp;
        else
        {
            first = head;
            rhead = reverse_list(temp->next);
            first->next = NULL;
            rhead->next = first;
            return rhead;
        }
    }
```

I can't find any mistakes in this but I still don't get the correct output.Please help.

Comment: -- deleted -- sorry, my mistake
Another tip: tell us what you have as output, it will make it easier for us too see what's wrong

Comment: @Pinna_be The question is not tagged `C++`. Therefore `struct node` is not equivalent to `node`.

Comment: @Pinna_be: If there isn't a `typedef`, the type of a structure is `struct tag`. You can omit the `struct` keyword in C++, but not in C.

Comment: Why do you want to use a recursive way? It is basically copying the pointers of all the list elements several times onto the stack. The problem is simple enough to just iterate over the list while modifying the references.

Comment: @Veger:I already have a solution using iteration,I am trying for one using recursion

Comment: @Pinna_be:I just get the last element(of the input array) which points to the first element (of the input array) as the output.The nodes in the middle are missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 consecutive nodes in order to do it recursively:

```
struct node* reverse_list(struct node *head)
    {
       return reverse_list_prev(null, head);
    }

struct node* reverse_list_prev(struct node *prev, struct node *current)
    {
        if(null==current)
            return prev;
        struct node *tmp = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        return reverse_list_prev(current, tmp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is not quite right to me

```
     rhead->next = first;
```

it seems to me it should traverse to the end of the `rhead` list and `tail` of that points to `first`.